# Cannot convert some classes but others can. C++

Tags: c++, oop, compiler-errors, bison

I have these rules in `parser.y`:

```
ident : TIDENTIFIER { $$ = new NIdentifier(*$1); delete $1; }
  ;
numeric : TINTEGER { $$ = NInteger(atol($1->c_str())); delete $1; }
  ;
```

When I compile with `g++ -o parser parser.y tokens.flex main.cpp` i get:

```
parser.y:82:63: error: cannot convert ‘NInteger’ to ‘NExpression*’ in assignment
TINTEGER { $$ = NInteger(atol($1->c_str())); delete $1; }
                                                 ^
```

These are the classes definitions:

```
class Node {
public:
  virtual ~Node() {}
};

class NExpression : public Node {
};

class NInteger : public NExpression {
public:
  long long value;
  NInteger(long long value) : value(value) { }
};

class NIdentifier : public NExpression {
public:
  std::string name;
  NIdentifier(const std::string& name) : name(name) { }
};
```

I don't understand why one class can be converted but the other can't, since both inherit from the same parent and both constructors have the same mechanism.

Comment: Looks like `NIdentifier` is being returned as a pointer, whereas `NInteger` is being returned by value.  You probably want a `new` before `NInteger`.

Comment: Wow, that should've been easy to spot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @md5i, I wasn't creating an `NInteger` instance with `new` so there was no object in the heap to reference to. This is fixed by adding the `new` operator in front of `NInteger`.

Comment: It does provide an answer: add `new` to create an instance of the class and have something to reference to. I'm just want to acknowledge who pointed out the error.

Comment: Sorry, thought you were referring to an existing answer rather than to a comment.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot convert an instance of a class to a pointer to an instance. Note the `*` in the error message.

In the rule which works, you set `$$` to `new NIdentifier`, which is a pointer to a new instance.

Answer (score 1):

```
ident : TIDENTIFIER { $$ = new NIdentifier(*$1); delete $1; }
  ;
numeric : TINTEGER { $$ = NInteger(atol($1->c_str())); delete $1; }
  ;
```

You forgot to put `new NInteger` like in the first row.